# Animate listing from left to right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done this animation in jQuery:

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  $('ul> li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(300 * i).animate({
      opacity: 1,
      left: 0
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  color: #34495e;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul>li:before {
  content: "\f105";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 31px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
  top: 7px;
  color: #6f6f6f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

I have to do the same animation using plain JavaScript because I need to integrate it in Angular.

Can any one help me in this or suggest any better approach?

Comment: Consider using angular animations: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: @C_Ogoo any suggestion using javascript or css ?

Answer (score 1):

With vanailla JS and CSS you could do the following:

```js
function animateList() {
  const items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  [...items].forEach((item, i) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      item.classList.add("animation");
    }, 300 * i);
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  color: #34495e;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.animation {
  transition: 800ms;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="animateList()">Animate!</button>
```

Comment: I need to disply the element by lazy loading, like element should move from left to right by  one after another

Comment: Ah I overlooked the `delay` in your jQuery. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `transition: all ease 800ms` to the `ul > li` in CSS will animate the elements as you want

For the delay & activation, you can either bind an EventListener:

```html
<button id="showList">Demo<button>
```

```js
document.getElementById('showList').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul > li').forEach(({style}, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {style.opacity = 1, style.left = 0}, 300 * i);
  });
});
```

Or attach the function to the onclick of the `<button>` element directly

```html
<button onclick="showList();">Demo</button>
```

```js
function showList() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul > li').forEach(({style}, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {style.opacity = 1, style.left = 0}, 300 * i);
  });
}
```

Here's a demo using the eventListener method:

```js
document.getElementById('showList').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul > li').forEach(({style}, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {style.opacity = 1, style.left = 0}, 300 * i);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul>li {
  transition: all ease 800ms;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  color: #34495e;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="showList">Demo</button>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: error Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

Comment: It works in the snippet, so I am unsure what the issue could be

Answer (score 0):

I have used Angular animations to achieve this. For delay in each li item I have used Angular `stagger`. Documentation for stagger can be found here: https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animate-stagger-purbue